# Laravel Nested Foreach

Tags: php, laravel

My Array

```
Array ( 
[1] => Array ( 
[username] => Test 
[description] => Hello
[country] => USA
[menu] => Array ( 
  [1] => Array ( 
    [id] => 1 
    [level] => 1 
    [level_2_categories] => Array (
          [level] => 2 
          [services] => Array (
              [1] ...
              [2] ...
              [3] ... )
  [2] => Array ( 
    [id] => 2 
    [level] => 1 
    [level_2_categories] => Array (
          [level] => 2  
          [services] => Array (
                      )
  [3] => Array ( 
    [id] => 3 
    [level] => 1 
    [level_2_categories] => Array ( 
          [level] => 2 
          [services] => Array (
              [1] ...
              [2] ...
              [3] ... )
  ) 
)
```

Laravel

```
@foreach ($professional->menu as $index => $menu)
  @foreach ($menu->level_2_categories as $category)
    @if (count($category->services)>0)
     <li>
       <a href="#{{ $menu->id}}" data-toggle="tab">
         <div class="category-box">
           <span class="arrow">{{ $menu->id }}</span>
         </div>
       </a>
     </li>
    @endif
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I am trying to print [id] for each of the menu arrays except those with no arrays in [services] (the second array for menu). Tried the code above but Laravel outputs the menu ids by multiple times due to the nested @foreach. Would appreciate any help thanks!

Comment: @BhaumikMehta The {{ $menu->id }} is being printed multiple times. I only want them to print each once.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try by maintaining the `count` as done in the code below:

```
@foreach ($professional->menu as $index => $menu)
    <?php $count=0;?> // change over here   
  @foreach ($menu->level_2_categories as $category)
    @if (count($category->services) > 0 && $count==0) // change over here
    <?php $count++; ?> // change over here
    <li>
      <a href="#{{ $menu->id}}" data-toggle="tab">
        <div class="category-box">
          <span class="arrow">{{ $menu->id }}</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    @endif
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Tried your code,  each {{ $menu->id}} is printed once now (which is what I want) but the second one (id => 2) is still printed

Answer (score -1):

Updated answer, if you are using a Laravel version > 5.3, you could use the built in `$loop` variable:

```
@foreach ($professional->menu as $index => $menu)
  @foreach ($menu->level_2_categories as $category)
    @if (count($category->services) > 0 && $loop->index == 0)
      <li>
        <a href="#{{ $menu->id}}" data-toggle="tab">
          <div class="category-box">
            <span class="arrow">{{ $menu->id }}</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
    @endif
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#loops